# Disable a frame before dispose

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, dispose

```
if("Back".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
{
    escape.setVisible(false);
    paused = false;
    running = !running;
    Graphics g = start.getGraphics();
    g.dispose();
    Component glassPane = start.getGlassPane();
    glassPane.setVisible(!glassPane.isVisible());
    Main.main(null);
    Main.running = true;
    start.dispose();
}
```

This is my code for disabling my jframe, loading a new one, and disposing it. Whenever I do this, when I return to the frame I get strange graphical errors.
[image: One of the graphical errors!]

How do I close the frame completly?

Comment: Can you upload that strange errors? And one advice: Don't load a new frame, make your game so you can load a new panel.

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Why do you dispose the graphics, did you create it? The rule is always that you dispose what you created. Also, I suppose that `start` is a JFrame. It's unlikely that you need to call `getGraphics()`,... ever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- create `private`/`public`(depends of your code design) variable for `JFrame` instance
- then you can't bothering with dispose of visible `JFrame` and then re_create a new one
- create `class` or `local instace` that returns `JPanel` with game content
- call `JFrame#getContentPane#removeAll(`)
- call `JFrame#getContentPane#add(new GamePanel())`
- maybe there are easiest ways how to reset whatever (depends of your code design) to the start_up statuses